# how to read a json file in vba word and store the json key values in array?

Tags: vba

```
{
    "IOP": {
        "journal": ["�ref_auSurname", "�ref_auGivenName", "�ref_auCollab", "�ref_etal", "�ref_titleArticle", "�ref_titleJournal", "�ref_pubdateYear", "�ref_volumeNumber", "�ref_issueNumber", "�ref_supplement", "�ref_pageFirst", "�ref_pageLast", "�ref_accessDate", "�ref_URL"],
        "book": ["�ref_auSurname", "�ref_auGivenName", "�ref_etal", "�ref_titleBook", "�ref_edition", "�ref_publisherLocation", "�ref_publisherName", "�ref_pubdateYear"]
            },
    "LWW": {
        "journal": [�ref_auSurname", "�ref_auGivenName", "�ref_etal"],
        "book": []
           }
}
```

EDIT: Code from comments below:

```
Dim JsonTS As TextStream
Dim JsonText As String
Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\9105122\Desktop\refspec.json", ForReading)
JsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll
Set JsonParse = JsonConverter.ParseJson(JsonText)
```

Above Json code is my input file. If I run JsonConverter( VBA-JSON converter from Tim Hall), till the "]" in IOP -> Journal, it is executing and value is stored in collection after this "]" in IOP -> Journal. I got the error as "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment". I can't read the content in IOP -> Book.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We cant give you specific help without you telling us your specific problem. General answer below.

Comment: How should the array look like? What values do you want each element to contain?

Comment: Have a look to the VBA-JSON converter from Tim Hall. It's really working great:  https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Answer (score 0):

To assign DSVs to an array, use the [Array()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262675(v=vs.60).aspx) function or the [Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) function.

Comment: Dim JsonTS As TextStream
Dim JsonText As String                                                                          Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\9105122\Desktop\refspec.json",ForReading)
JsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll                                                                                   I dono how to store the value in array...

Comment: Don't post code in the comments, update your question with your code instead. Read the documentation for the `Array()` function I posted above, format your string accordingly and use it as a parameter for the function.

Comment: Edited and added comment to your question.

Comment: If I run that code, till the "]" in IOP -> Journal, it is executing well after that I got the error as "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment". I can't read the content in IOP -> Book.

Comment: Update your question with your code, mark the part that throws the error and describe your input data.